# How to find a set of paths from n sources to n target?

Tags: path, graph-theory, ford-fulkerson

I'm exploring a problem where I am wanting to find valid paths from multiple sources with each having a different target. I.e. a path from point a to b and a path from point c to d where the previous path from point a to b does not invalidate the path from c to d. The paths don't need to be the shortest path they just need to be valid.

The idea is that this would be working with a grid of hexagons. Like this.
[Hexagon grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWDtz.png)

With this idea in mind, each path could possibly visit the same node that a previous path did with the constraint being that they can not enter from the same node or exit to the same next node. An example of a valid path like would be: [Valid Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZh8N.jpg)

Likewise an invalid path would be like this: [Invalid path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1uI8.jpg)

It's interesting and I'm currently looking into the ford-fulkerson algorithm as a possibility but if anybody had any other ideas or insight it would be greatly appreciated! If you are curious for any info I may have missed please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [Bellman–Ford algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm).

Comment: Or you can go the hard way and try all the possibilities while keeping track of visited nodes.